# How to make a button in react.js to make a text toggle from appearing to disappearing?

Tags: reactjs

I want to create a button so that when i click on it, it makes a text appear, and on second click, disappears, on third, appears again... and so on.

```
  class App extends Component {
   constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isShow: false,
    }      
   this.createText = this.createText.bind(this);
   this.condrender = this.condrender.bind(this);
    }

createText() {
 this.setState({ isShow: true });
}

 condrender() {
  if (this.state.isShow===true) {
   return (
    <p>THIS TEXT</p>
   ); 
 }
}

 render() {
   return (
    <div className="App">
     <button onClick={this.createText}>Click</button>
      {this.condrender()}
    </div>
     );
   }
  }
 }
```

With this code, the text appears when i click on the button. So I added this line `this.setState({isShow: false})`, and I get an error.

```
  condrender() {
    if (this.state.isShow===true) {
     this.setState({isShow: false})
     return (
      <p>THIS TEXT</p>
      ); 
     }
    }
```

> Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as
>   within render or another component's constructor). Render methods
>   should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects
>   are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`

My thinking is that after I set it to false, the text will disappear since isShow's state will be false. Please help me understand the error and how to go around this?

Comment: It works for me: [`jsfiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/185863/)

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty straight foward. On every click you just set the state to the opposite of itself. You can use a ternary to render.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';

class App extends React.Component 
{
  constructor() 
  {
    super();
    this.state = 
    {
      isShow: false,
    }
    this.ToggleText = this.ToggleText.bind(this);
  }

  ToggleText() 
  {
    let state = { ...this.state };
    state.isShow = !state.isShow;
    this.setState(state);
  }

  render() 
  {
    let element = <p>THIS TEXT</p>
    
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.ToggleText}>Click</button>
        {
          this.state.isShow ? element : null
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 1):

This warning is shown, as you are calling a method in render method and then trying to set state in that method.

Instead, what you can do is :

```
class App extends Component {
   constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isShow: false,
    }      
   this.createText = this.createText.bind(this);
   this.condrender = this.condrender.bind(this);
    }

createText() {
 this.setState({ isShow: !this.state.isShow});
}

 condrender() {
   return (
    <p>THIS TEXT</p>
   ); 
 }
}

 render() {
   return (
    <div className="App">
     <button onClick={this.createText}>Click</button>
      {this.state.isShow ? this.condrender() : null}
    </div>
     );
   }
  }
 }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Set state to the nagative of the previous state and all will be done !

`createText() {
   this.setState({ isShow: !this.state.isShow });
}`